# The jquery is not displaying correctly on IE7

Tags: jquery, browser, accordion

I have an application where I'm using nested jquery, when I want to see the content of the accordion, it does not display until i mouse over on the content. I don't have this problem on firefox. Has any1 face this problem before? Any advice?

Comment: When posting code for HTML/CSS/JS problems, please post the generated client side code, not the server side source code. Open page in webbrowser and do a 'view source'.

Comment: plus this part of code is formed by ajax,it doesn't exist when you do view source.

Answer (score 2):

> *it does not display until i mouse over on the content.*

Sounds like IE's hasLayout bug (which should also occur on IE6 but not IE8 by the way). Ensure that you're using the strict doctype and carefully read [this article](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html).

Answer (score 0):

Jquery is working fine cross browser. I would say that you're doing something wrong (like some other javascript crashing before actually using jQuery or using JS functions that are not IE*-compliant).

Some code would help pinpoint what you're doing wrong.